# Facebook Connect XFBML not working

Tags: firefox, facebook, xfbml

I'm making a website using Facebook Connect and decided to use Facebook's XFBML tags like "fb:profile-pic" since they are so easy to use.

I haven't been able to make them work no matter how hard I look online but then I noticed that it worked on all the browser's instead of Firefox.

I also realized that even on Facebook's own "The Run Around" sample app they don't work!! You can check it out here: http://www.somethingtoputhere.com/therunaround/index.php

If you log in with Firefox your picture is not shown, but if you use another browser it is shown. This happens with the fb:profile-pic tag or any other tag like fb:name.

I haven't found any information online so I'm asking other people that have worked with this: Are these tags simply not compatible with Firefox ? Do they have outages or something like that ? Has this happened to anyone before ? Any ideas on how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess they do have "outages". I've spent the whole weekend trying to resolve this and now they post they had a problem and have resolved it.

From the **Platform Live Status** website:

http://developers.facebook.com/live_status.php#msg_497

> We are experiencing a possible config
>   problem with api.connect.facebook.com.
>   If you are including Connect JS
>   library through
>   http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php,
>   all API requests through JavaScript
>   would fail. This affects rendering of
>   XFBML tags (such as fb:name and
>   fb:profile-pic) as well. While we are
>   fixing this issue, you can work around
>   the problem by changing
>   http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php
>   to
>   http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php.
>   It's also safe to keep url change
>   permanently because
>   connect.facebook.com is just an alias
>   to facebook.com.

I wish they had updated that sooner, now I'm looking for a place to find out about this stuff before I spend days working on something before realizing it's not a problem with my code!

Comment: New url for **Facebook Platform Live Status** is https://developers.facebook.com/live_status

Answer (score 0):

Open up **Firefox > Preferences > Privacy** and make sure "Accept third party cookies" is checked. This is needed for Facebook Connect to work. Also, when using Connect, make sure all your tags are fully closed, i.e. `<fb:profile-pic></fb:profile-pic>` and not `<fb:profile-pic/>`. From the docs:

> The user's browser must be set to
>   accept 3rd Party Cookies in order for
>   it to stay connected between clicks.

Source: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Logging_In_And_Connecting

FWIW, I wouldn't use "the run around" as a sample app. That thing has been the same since they introduced Connect and is pretty hacky.

Comment: I have Firefox set to allow third party cookies and all my tags are closed properly. This doesn't only happen in my computer, I've checked a couple more on the same thing happens there too. Thanks for the suggestions though, those are things worth checking, but not the issue in this case. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Huh, you know what? All my Facebook Connect apps are currently failing as well. I think the "platform is down". Nothing on their status page though: http://developers.facebook.com/live_status.php Welcome to Facebook Connect development! "It works sometimes" should be thier slogan. You can see it failing on one of my apps here: http://charactersunite.com/discussions/view/6 No names or photos. Was working yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

do check in connect section under the canvas option.
there should be a link of your physical file.